# How do I make telephone numbers in iPhone clickable?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have some telephone numbers in UILabel in various cells of a UITableView.

I also have telephone numbers in the subtitle of MKAnnotations in my MapViews.

How I can make these telephone numbers clickable so that they launch the phone app on the iPhone and dial the number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only `UITextView` handles this automatically.

Anything else will require you to make the call yourself (by responding to a tap, for instance):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:15415551234"]];
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that tel:... will immediately leave the app the dial the phone number, and when the call is done they remain in the phone app. Alternatively, telprompt:... will ask the user if they want to call the number, and when they are done with the call the original app will be brought back to the foreground.